# How to handle two networks (one for Smart devices and another to access internet) in a home automation setup?

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, home-automation, security

I want to use my Raspberry Pi 4 as a secure home automation server that can handle two networks: one for accessing smart devices (over WiFi) and another for accessing the internet. This setup should be more secure as only the Pi has access to the web (for example to get Weather data) and the smart devices can use this data stored locally without having access to the internet. I am currently using Hassio but I am willing to change to other platforms (if needed) to get support for the above described feature.

Comment: This should work as is - assuming both networks have DHCP servers and different network segments. You should explain in more detail how the networks are configured. Include the output of ip a & ip r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup an access point that the smart devices can connect. Then you can connect the RasPi wired to your internet router but don't enable routing. This way the smart devices can use data on the RasPi but cannot connect to the internet. Only the RasPi can get into the internet so it can get data from there and store it local. You can find an example at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). Just follow section **♦ Setting up an access point and with eth0, without routing**.